# Magento 2: making a module using UI component compatible both 2.0 and 2.1?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento-2.0, uicomponent

As you may know, there are many differences in the way the UI components work on Magento 2.0 and Magento 2.1.

I find it **very painful having to manage two different versions of the same module when using UI components (one version for 2.0 and one for 2.1).** Cross version compatibility is important IMO specially when you are a module provider so the customer don't have to double check the version to know which module to install.

Thus I would like to make my module compatible with both.

Here is the idea I came up with:

- Having two different UI components under the `ui_component` folders: `my_listing_v_2_0.xml` and `my_listing_v_2_1.xml`
- Then in my layout file I could do something like this:

  ```
  <uiComponent ifversion="2.0" name="my_listing_v_2_0" />
  <uiComponent ifversion="2.1" name="my_listing_v_2_1" />
  ```

That is the theory, and in theory it could work fine.

Now here come the questions:

- how do I attack this ?
- **Any way I can create conditional UI component declaration in my layout file ?** I highly doubt that's possible out of the box but I'm willing to write some extra code so the layout can support such thing.
- even better (doubt it's possible), **can we make a UI component file compatible both 2.0 and 2.1 ?**

Answer (score 2):

This is untested, but if I was going to try to do this I'd try a plugin on the `uiComponent` Reader/Scheduler class.  You'll probably want to read this [10,000 foot view](http://magento-quickies.alanstorm.com/post/139615758780/magento-2-10000-ft-layout-rendering-view) post explain layout rendering in Magento 2, but the short version is the following class/method

```
#File: project-community-edition/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Reader/UiComponent.php
public function interpret(Context $readerContext, Layout\Element $currentElement)
{
    $attributes = $this->getAttributes($currentElement);
    $scheduledStructure = $readerContext->getScheduledStructure();
    $referenceName = $this->layoutHelper->scheduleStructure(
        $scheduledStructure,
        $currentElement,
        $currentElement->getParent(),
        ['attributes' => $attributes]
    );

    $scheduledStructure->setStructureElementData($referenceName, ['attributes' => $attributes]);
    $configPath = (string)$currentElement->getAttribute('ifconfig');
    if (!empty($configPath)) {
        $scheduledStructure->setElementToIfconfigList($referenceName, $configPath, $this->scopeType);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

is where Magento reads Layout XML values and tells the layout object to "schedule" the creation of a layout structure (block, uiComponent, container, etc.) object.  This eventually leads to the creation of that element when Magento finally renders the layout.

A plugin on this method that looks for your `uiComponent`, and then modifies the component's name might work.